# how to view php and server error logs?

Tags: error-handling

I am getting the WSOD now since editing settings.php; php.ini and .htaccess trying to update my site and I need to see error logs to find out what is happening.

Also how do you clear cache in command line?

Answer (score 3):

First of all:

- The logs for apache are set in the `httpd.conf` file.
- And the logs for PHP (if any) are set in the `php.ini` file.

For the case of PHP, you have to look at the `php.ini` file, and look for `log_errors` and `error_log` variables, that must have these values:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /tmp/php_error.log
```

the last value (**/tmp/php_error.log**) is just an example. It must be a path to a secure location where you want to store the logs.

Make sure that:

- these two lines are not commented, i.e.: they cannot have any `;` before them.
- after the edit is done, restart apache to load these values.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: read the above works as well but did not notice any errors in php.ini. I think I need to dump the database which I am also unsure of how to do without making a mess.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, PHP's error messages will appear in Apache's error log by default. Try checking there (it's `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on Debian) for messages mentioning PHP.

Comment: I read that too and found a command to reveal error_log but when I looked for it to edit couldn't find.

Comment: This is great thanks, I found it in /var/log/httpd/error_log and it seems some files are missing like robot.txt so thanks again.